# How windows forms Gridview is different from asp.net gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am experienced in asp.net and it's tools, i always use gridview to fill it with data from database, i usually edit it in .aspx code and rarely in .cs code but i am newbie to windows forms gridview, how it is different from asp.net's gridview. It doesn't have behind code, can it only be edited from wizard and properties etc or any other way ?

Comment: What do you mean by *It doesn't have behind code*? Also what gridview you're talking about? `DataGridView` or?

Comment: Windows forms has very limited native declarative capabilities for control manipulation, so, with exception of some simple binding scenarios, you will have to use a lot of code-behind to get the desired look and behaviour. And for now this question is a bit unclear and far too broad. Can you clarify the `is different` part of the question: Different in what - interaction, templating, behaviour...?

Comment: liker it only have .cs code and i m talking about C#.net DataGridview, winforms

Comment: @EugenePodskal i mean that in asp.net girdview we can put template tags etc, lots of color tags, binding, adding and deleting columns via column tag etc but it doesn't exist in winforms

Comment: Windows forms form(or user control) usually consists of two files - designer and code-behind. Both of them are .cs. There are no markup declarations, like .aspx in ASP.NET or .xaml in WPF. Everything is done either through code directly or through wizards indirectly. Well, there are probably some libraries that provide declarative model, but I never used them.

Comment: `Datagridview` has `DataGridViewColumn` collection which you can modify from designer.  
You can add different type of columns(button, text, checkbox...), you can bind columns to fields of `DataSource`, you can handling behavior through `datagridview` event handlers... And so on...

Comment: so what practice should be carried on further ? designer or code ?

Comment: You can do both. When you do something in designer, Visual Studio just generate code in `yourform.designer.cs` file, and "code behind" file `yourform.cs` is for developer code. Start with designer

Comment: Agree with @EugenePodskal: *"Windows forms has very limited [...] capabilities for"* ... **Everything**. You're much better off using current, non deprecated, usable technology.

Comment: so any other way to fill data apart from gridviews ? it seems boring and dull old fashioned gridviews

Answer (score 2):

The major difference in ASP.NET databound controls classes from their WinForms counterparts is in the object lifecycle and user interaction.

You can see that DataGridView contains much more methods then GridView.

[DataGridView Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) - 400.

[GridView Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) - 147.

This is due to the fact that WinForms controls handle user interaction in-process, and are responsible for handling mouse events, keyboard events and dynamic layout manipulation.
ASP.NET controls are usually limited to what can be implemented with renderd HTML. As a basic feature, Javascript is only used when it's absolutely needed for WebForms functionality, such as postbacks and partial update panels. Consider the following method in DataGridView: AutoResizeRow(Int32). There's no such method the ASP.NET's GridView, because this kind of method would require javascript manipulation that is too much related to the HTML rendering engine in browsers. The same applies to mouse and keyboard events.

As for data manipulation methods, ASP.NET databound controls contain pretty much the same set of functionality. The difference here is that data must be manipulated out-of-process, and the controls state must be serialized so it could be restored back before handling postback events on server side.

ASP.NET requires control instances to be recreated each time a server side event occurs.
That is why ASP.NET GridView contains {Load,Save}{ViewState,ControlState} methods.

In WinForms, on the contrary, only a single control instance is needed the same part of view. The state lives in-process and does not need to be serialized.

As for the designer support and codebehind - it works pretty much the same way.